# mySQL how to display NULL as 0

Tags: mysql, sql, join, null, subquery

Trying to get my code to show 0 rather than NULL when no data is present:

```
SELECT e.EntryName AS Name, e.EntryDate AS Date,

(SELECT COALESCE(COUNT(l.crashNumber), 0)
FROM Crash l
WHERE l.crashName = e.EntryName 
AND l.crashDate = e.EntryDate
GROUP BY l.crashNumber
ORDER BY COUNT(l.crashNumber) DESC
LIMIT 1)

FROM 
(SELECT e.EntryName, e.EntryDate
FROM Entry e
GROUP BY e.EntryName, e.EntryDate)

e;
```

As you can see I've tried using COALESCE, I've tried using ISNULL.
The idea is that not all races have crashes so their output is displayed as NULL, though I wish for when it is NULL it should display 0.

Comment: Get the coalesce to wrap the entire correlated query and not the count it self.. coalesce(select count...,0)

Comment: That gives me a syntax error

Comment: You need parentheses around `select`: `coalesce((select count...), 0)`

Comment: I feel dirty just looking at that select in the select.  Use a derrived table so the query doesn't have to execute once for each record in raceentry.

Comment: Thank you sagi and Barmar, and xQbert I've no idea what that is, but I shall research it, thank you for advice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
SELECT e.raceEntryRaceName AS raceName, e.raceEntryRaceDate AS raceDate,

Coalesce( ( SELECT COUNT(l.pitstopRaceNumber)
           FROM PitStops l
           WHERE l.pitstopRaceName = e.raceEntryRaceName 
             AND l.pitstopRaceDate = e.raceEntryRaceDate
           GROUP BY l.pitstopRaceNumber
           ORDER BY COUNT(l.pitstopRaceNumber) DESC
           LIMIT 1), 0) AS mostPitstops

FROM .....
```

Comment: This is perfect.
Note: edited my post to try and make columns easier to understand.